# What mean points all over Q-Q plot?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, normal-distribution, python, qq-plot

I printed the Q-Q plot for my data and it came out like this. Obviously, the data is not following the normal distribution, but what else can we say about the data basing on such output?

[image]

Comment: There must be something wrong: a QQ-Plot plots a function, not a relation. It is thus impossible that one x-value corresponds to several y-values.

Comment: The y-axis looks a bit off to me as well - it is 1/100th the scale of the x-axis. If you zoom out (s.t. the "y=x line" is actually y=x) it will look as a flat line.

Comment: @cdalitz what can be a reason of the fact that some x values correspond to y values?

Comment: Your method probably requires the data to be sorted first.